# Showing home button in a specified menu

Tags: menus

I try to add the home button in a specified WordPress menu (I have 2) and it's not working at all.

This is my code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'show_home' => $args['show_home'] = true)); ?>
```

Calling the 'global $args;' didn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show_home` isn't working for you because there is no `show_home` argument on `wp_nav_menu`. You will need to add it using the menu editor in the admin panel, most likely as a custom link.

These are the valid arguments:

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

You've likely been given an example that has confused `wp_nav_menu` with `wp_page_menu`, which *does* have a `show_home` argument

Comment: As an extra note, you could modify `items_wrap` to include the markup for the first menu item, using `home_url()` as the URL, but experienced developers would frown upon this

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I'm gonna remove the wrong part of that code, then.